# After sudo apt update on Debiabn can't connect ssh, how to fix?

Tags: ssh, debian

set Sublim by manual [this](https://wiki.debian.org/SublimeText)

after all the steps finish thrown out of the ssh client and every time you connect instantly disconnect always, (after `sudo apt update`)

sshd_conf is not changed,

the site works normally,

access via FTP works

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems to be a common problem with upgrading to buster, `sudo systemctl restart sshd` (or just reboot)

Comment: how can I register a command if I can't connect via ssh?

Comment: use the console (if present), or BMC (if remote eg: IPMI,IDRAC,LISH) or ask the hoster to reboot it if neither is an option.